# Crear una regla en regedit con C++

Tags: c++

Hola quiero que mi aplicación mia se arranque desde el startup es decir al arranque de mi windows. Es una aplicación que utilizo muy amenudo y es molesto iniciarlo repetidas veces. Bueno lo que quiero mi valor de la subclave sea la ruta del programa que estoy usando. 
Lo que llevo hasta ahora es:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HKEY * key;
    LPCTSTR ruta = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
    long status = RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, ruta, key);
    string valor;
    string subclave;
    LPCTSTR _subclave = TEXT(subclave.c_str());
    LPCTSTR _valor = TEXT(valor.c_str());
    long crear = RegSetValueEx(*key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)_valor, strlen(_valor) * sizeof(char));
    return 0;
}
```

Pero me muestra varios errores como que no reconoce la subclave y tal:
[image: no reconoce subclave]

Y quería que el valor de mi subclave sea la ruta de mi programa arrancado. Alguna solución o conocen el motivo de estos errores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La macro `TEXT` espera recibir una variable de tipo `LPTSTR`, siendo el tipo `LPTSTR` un alias de `char*`:

```
void TEXT(
   LPTSTR string
);
```

Y sin embargo tu código intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
string subclave;
LPCTSTR _subclave = TEXT(subclave.c_str());
```

Si miras la documentación sobre `c_str()`, verás que devuelve un puntero de tipo `const char` y dicho tipo no va a ser compatible directamente con los tipos esperados por la macro `TEXT`.

Por otro lado, el tipo `LPCSTR` es, directamente, un alias de `const char*`. Es decir, la conversión que realizas debería quedar así:

```
LPCTSTR _subclave = subclave.c_str();
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que no estás dando valores ni a `subclave` ni a `valor`, luego la llamada:

```
long crear = RegSetValueEx(*key, _subclave, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)_valor, strlen(_valor) * sizeof(char));
```

Va a recibir dos parámetros en blanco.